# Manually set offset for kafka group id

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have set up my kafka platform using the Confluent platform (v3.2.0).

My consumers/producers -applications are programmed in C# using the NuGet package "[Confluent-Kafka](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Confluent.Kafka)" to add/get data to my kafka streams.

I wonder if it is possible to set the offset for a specific consumer group id for a topic so the consumer that has that group id "rollback" to the offset I set?

My idea is to be able to do this outside of my consumer application, prefered in a admin-ui that I need to build. I just need to know how to communicate this with the kafka platform. Can this be done using a cli command or a rest api?

Comment: Can you show us your existing code that reads from Kafka?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Apache Kafka 0.11 (Confluent platform v3.3) there are new options to the bin/kafka-consumer-groups command line tool to allow the reset of offsets for a consumer group. You can set the offset based on either a numeric offset or time. You can also do relative offset adjustments such as rewind 100 messages or go back 5 minutes.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-122%3A+Add+Reset+Consumer+Group+Offsets+tooling

```
--reset-offsets                         Reset offsets of consumer group.
                                      Supports one consumer group at the
                                      time, and instances should be
                                      inactive
                                    Has 3 execution options: (default) to
                                      plan which offsets to reset, --
                                      execute to execute the reset-offsets
                                      process, and --export to export the
                                      results to a CSV format.
                                    Has the following scenarios to choose:
                                      --to-datetime, --by-period, --to-
                                      earliest, --to-latest, --shift-by, --
                                      from-file, --to-current. One
                                      scenario must be choose
                                    To define the scope use: --all-topics
                                      or --topic. . One scope must be
                                      choose, unless you use '--from-file'
                                      scenario
```

Comment: Nice! Where can I find v3.3.0 of confluent? Current release is 3.2.2 on their website.

Comment: Coming any day now.

Comment: Nice! Are there breaking changes so I have to upgrade my c# client to use 3.3.0?

Comment: Don't think so. Should work with 3.2 client and 3.3 broker

Comment: It's been a month now, any updates when it's gonna be released @hans-jespersen?

Comment: @Raskolnikoov there were quite a few bugs to fix but it looks like it should be out by the end of this week.

Answer (score 1):

You can when you get assignments from the coordinator. See last message here:

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/141
With the current API, you can't jump or go back in a partition, you will have to unsubscribe/subscribe again, but you can easily add this in your code

Comment: Yes from the consumer itself its possible. But I want to be able to do this outside of the consumer. Like in a admin ui i can build that make calls to the kafka server and modifies the group topics offsets

Comment: You could add a topic sending the groupid, topi and partition and all consumers would listen and operate on this. But Hans Jespersen answer is best if you upgrade to incoming kafka/confluent version